# laravel conditional db query

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

How would I do a conditional laravel query taking in consideration what I try and did not work, where I try to get get products with a specifc name if name is not empty

**This one is not working!!**

```
public function getProducts($page = null, $match=null, $price = null) {
    if ($page != null)
        DB::getPaginator()->setCurrentPage($page);
        $products = Product::join('product_specs', 'products.productid', '=', 'product_specs.product_id')
                ->join('feeds_categories', 'product_specs.category', '=', 'feeds_categories.id')
                ->where('feeds_categories.name', '=', 'Notebooks')
                ->where('products.status', '=', 1)
                ->where('products.price', '>', 250)
                ->orderBy('products.price', 'ASC')
                ->paginate(10);
   if($match !='') $products->where('productname','LIKE','%'.$match.'%');    
   return $products;
}
```

Comment: An empty string and null  are different. Have you tried testing $match for null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not reassign the query builder back to the `$products` variable. Try this:

```
if($match !='') $products = $products->where('productname','LIKE','%'.$match.'%');
```

In fact, you will also need to move it before `->paginate(10)` as well.

```
public function getProducts($page = null, $match=null, $price = null) {

        ...
        ->where('products.price', '>', 250); // Notice I added a semi-colon here.

    if($match !='') $products = $products->where('productname','LIKE','%'.$match.'%'); 

    $products = $products->orderBy('products.price', 'ASC')
        ->paginate(10);

    return $products;
}
```